# Making an array out of variables and update its contents based on one of the variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, syntax, calendar

I have a question that pertains to gathering events from tables in a calendar program where they are separated into "events" or "repeated events".  I can get all individual events perfectly well now (thanks to Chris on this site), but if they are repeating events I have to calculate it from what is given in this particular db.  If I change the types or the data in the db, it will probably trash the calendar so I have to use what I have.

The variables I have sorted out so far are:

- `$quid2` = The IDs for today's events that are classified as repeating events (needed earlier)
- `$quname` = The repeated event names
- `$qucls` = The date UNIX time for the last sent reminder of events dated today
- `$qutype` = One of these words - daily, weekly, monthly or yearly
- `$qudesc` = A description of the event

These variables all have the same number of items and are ordered correctly between each other. (I Hope)

Below is the logic I am trying to accomplish.  It are most assuredly not proper syntax but I think it is understandable; I need to figure out what the syntax and form is.  I am utterly and completely new at this... so please be gentle...

It needs to be put in an array (I think)

```
$arr1 = some type of array($quname, $qucls, $qutype, $qudesc)
```

update the array...

- IF `$qutype($row2)` = "daily", then + 1440 to it's `$qucls($row[1])`
- IF `$qutype($row2)` = "weekly", then + 10080 to it's `$qucls($row[1])`
- IF `$qutype($row2)` = "monthly, then + 1 month to it's `$qucls($row[1])`
- IF `$qutype($row2)` = "yearly", then + 1 year to it's `$qucls($row[1])`

Then final product...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($arr1, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $UxTime = $row[1];
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    $Time = date("H:i", $UxTime);
    $qufinal = sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $row[0], $Time, $row[3);
}

...
```

This is a big learning project for me.  I don't know enough PHP and mysql to make this work but I know just enough to get me in trouble.  Thanks!

EDIT:  adding the queries from which I made these variables:

```
$today = date("Ymd");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query1 = "SELECT cal_id, cal_name, cal_date, cal_time, cal_type, cal_description FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_type = "M" AND cal_date != " . $today;

$wequ1 = mysql_query($query1)

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wequ1, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $quid1 = $row[0], $quname = $row[1], $qutime = $row[2], $qudesc = $row[3];
}

$query2 = "SELECT cal_id, cal_type, cal_ByDay FROM webcal_entry_repeats WHERE cal_id = " . $quid1;

$wer1 = mysql_query($query2)

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wer1, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $quid2 = $row[0] $qutype = $row[1], $qubdy = $row[2];
}

$query3 = "SELECT cal_id, cal_last_sent FROM webcal_reminders WHERE cal_id = " . $quid2;

    $wer2 = mysql_query($query3)

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wer2, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $qucls = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you post your table DDL combined with your expected output.  Here is a link to a recent question that deals with querying one off and recurring events - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232924/mysql-query-for-date-part/9233614#9233614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for arrays is as follows:

```
$arrayName = array($quname, $qucls, $qutype, $qudesc);
```

Then you can access the values by their index on the array variable:

```
$arrayName[0] == $quname
$arrayName[1] == $qucls
...
```

You can also define it as associative array:

```
$arrayName = array(
  "quname" => $quname, 
  "qucls" => $qucls, 
  "qutype" => $qutype, 
  "qudesc" => $qudesc
);
```

Using this syntax you can access the elements by their name:

```
$arrayName["quname"] == $quname
$arrayName["qucls"] == $qucls
...
```

More reading on this: [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

However, you don't really need an array for what you plan to do here. Arrays are very useful if you want to store data that is structurally equal. This applies e.g. to rows in a database: They always have the same number of entries, and the columns are of the same type.

If you have just one dataset at that point of code (one event in this case), then you need no array. Of course you have several events, but as they are processed in a loop (I assume) you handle only one event at a time, and then head to the next.

So, you want to modify a variable depending on the value `$qutype`. To do that, you can use a [`switch` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
$dateObj = date_create("@$qucls");

switch($qutype) {
  case "daily":
    date_add($dateObj, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"));
    break;
  case "weekly":
    date_add($dateObj, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 week"));
    break;
  case "monthly":
    date_add($dateObj, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 month"));
    break;
  case "yearly":
    date_add($dateObj, date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 year"));
    break;
}

$qucls = date_format($dateObj, "U");
```

I don't add the number of seconds, because that would work for days and weeks- but not for months and years, as they don't have a fixed number of seconds.

If you have questions about the functions I used above you can look up their documentation on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/).

In the code you show you must not use [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).
That function is only meant for result rows you got from a call to `mysql_query`, but not for normal arrays.

You don't need the while loop either. All you have to do is formatting `$qucls` to a readable format and produce the final string:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$Time = date("H:i", $qucls);
$qufinal = sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $quname, $Time, $qudesc);
```

---

**Edit:**

Like discussed in the comments here is the revised and commented code you edited in:

```
$today = date("Ymd");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// You need to use single quotes at the 'M'. Using double quotes will 
// end the string and thus leading to incorrect syntax 
$query1 = "SELECT cal_id, cal_name, cal_date, cal_time, cal_type, cal_description FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_type = 'M' AND cal_date != " . $today;

$wequ1 = mysql_query($query1);

// This is a counter variable which is incremented in the loop
$i = 0;

// This is the outer while loop used to gather and store the events
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wequ1, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    // Store the results in arrays
    
    // Statements must be seperated by a ;  
    $quid1[$i] = $row[0];
    $quname[$i] = $row[1];
    $qutime[$i] = $row[2];
    $qudesc[$i] = $row[3];

    $query2 = "SELECT cal_id, cal_type, cal_ByDay FROM webcal_entry_repeats WHERE cal_id = " . $quid1[$i];
    
    $wer1 = mysql_query($query2);
    
    // Assuming that IDs are unique this query can only return one entry. Therefore no while is 
    // needed, but an if statement tests if the ID actually matched a result
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wer1, MYSQL_NUM)) {        
        //$quid2[$i] = $row[0];   <- the query above ensures that $quid1[$i] == $quid2[$i]. No need to store it again
        $qutype[$i] = $row[1];
        $qubdy[$i] = $row[2];
    }
    
    $query3 = "SELECT cal_id, cal_last_sent FROM webcal_reminders WHERE cal_id = " . $quid1[$i];
    
    $wer2 = mysql_query($query3);
    
    // Same as above; If the IDs are unique then you need no loop
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($wer2, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        // The $i++ used here is the short form. As this is the last time $i is 
        // used in the loop it needs to be increased before the next round. You can do 
        // this like this or in an extra statement. This way it's evaluated and then increased
        $qucls[$i++] = $row[1];
    }
    
    // End outer while loop
}

// Now go through the results. $i holds the number of entries in the arrays + 1

// Secondary counter variable and for-loop
for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
    
    // Adding the dates to $qucls, formatting the string, ...
    // Access them like above: $qucls[$j]
    // Do not increase $j manually though - the for loop does that for you already
    
}
```

Please note that this code is untested. It's syntactically correct though.

On a side note: You are currently using three different database queries to gather the data.
You can easily merge them into a single query using SQL `JOIN`s. If you want somebody to show you how to do that, you can show them in a seperate question and ask for them to be joined into one.

Comment: Thanks again Chris. This is quite fascinating, and your comments are clear and informative. You must be a teacher.  I'll apply your comments and I am pretty sure I will get where I need to go.

Comment: Just for my own clarification, each of the 5 variables I mentioned at the top of this post are already arrays of retrieved data queried before, that represent events not repeated and are on today's date.  If there were 3 events that meet that criteria, then each of those variables would have 3 items in matching order and type.  Doesn't this mean I would need an array of these variables so I can make the change to individual items in &qucls based on items in $qutype?

Comment: I suppose to be more clear, I should give you the queries from which I got those variables,  `code` Sorry, I can't seem to add code here.  I'll make an edit to the main entry.

Comment: @defacto7: I'm not a teacher, no :-) The code you edited looks good, but it does not produce arrays. The five variables mentioned contain only one value each (as they are not arrays), because you overwrite their previous values in the loops. So what will happen is that they will contain the values from the last loop execution, and the previous ones are lost. There are two options: You can either do the processing (adding the dates, generating the message) inside a loop, then you don't need arrays. The second option is storing the values in arrays (comment to long, will continue below)

Comment: ... and then loop through the results and create the message from it. I personally would prefer the last because it's more overviewable, but opinions differ here. If you want, I can edit my answer to give you an example of how to do that. In that case please let me know which option you'd prefer.

Comment: Chris, you are very helpful, indeed.  I prefer option 2 using arrays.  I'm sure I need to learn the loop methods sometime but I have jumped into the array idea, maybe prematurely, but at least I have an idea of what it means.  Option 2 please.  Thanks

Comment: One more clarification of your array, please.  The first query is of table "webcal_entry" where the calendar entries are filtered by 'M' which means repeating entries and by the date that it is not,(today). This leaves me with the IDs of those results and their respective queried rows.  This could be 1, 2 or 20 different id's, names, dates etc.  con't...

Comment: The second query filters further using the table "webcal_entry_repeats" where there may be more id entries that I don't want and I am choosing only the IDs and their respective rows that are the same as those IDs queried in the first.  Does your example accomplish this or is there a logic I am missing?  Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I figured it out.  I think it does what I want it to do.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @defacto7: I understood that in your second and third query you only want to query entries from `webcal_entry_repeats` that match the IDs returned in the first query. The code does exactly this, and if there are 1,2 or 20 such entries then your array has 1,2 or 20 entries after execution.

Comment: Perfect!  It just takes me a moment to digest.  Now I see how it comes together.

Comment: Is the "Switch" routine you posted above still applicable to the new array edit?  I keep getting a Boolean instead of a DateTime error in "$qucls = date_format($dateObj, "U");". My first impression of this would be an error in the data being queried but I don't think it is.  I put the switch routine just after the new array above. Thanks